# Qt Creator compile mingw error (windows)

Tags: c++, qt, mingw, qt-creator

I have successfully compiled Qt Creator using mingw. I'm doing this so that Qt creator will recognize qwt plotting widgets. Qt creator is compiled in Visual Studio. Upon completion, in accordance with this VoidRealms tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zyG_gex9Ojs), i copy and paste the old Qt folder as an archive and then paste the contents of the Qt Creator build file into the Tools\bin folder.

This in theory will over right existing instances of each file (as in Qtcreator.exe will be over written with the newly compiled version, and so will each new dll).

So after all the copying and pasting i attempt to run qtcreator.exe and it pops up the following error (click link to view error window): [error with Qt5Core.dll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcxHn.png)

Any Ideas on why this might be happening??? Thanks in advance, Jordan

Comment: ***Any Ideas on why this might be happening???*** Was this Qt dll built with mingw? You can't use Qt dlls compiled with Visual Studio for a mingw build.

Comment: It may be compiled with Visual Studio. All i know is that if you try and run just the mingw compile without the other dll's then you get a missing dll error and if you run with the other dll's you get the error that i showed previously (can't read the dll).